# jQuery - Remove HTML values

Tags: jquery

I have some value in my HTML that I want to remove:

```
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
   <div class="sputility-readonly">12</div>
   99.99        
</td>
```

I want to remove '99.99' is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter the content for text node :

```
$('.ms-formbody').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3; //nodeType 3 is a text node.
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o86upesc/1/

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can detach the `div` element from the `td` using [jQuery's `detach()` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) then clear the HTML and add the `div` back in:

```
var div = $('td.ms-formbody').find('div').detach();

$('td.ms-formbody').html('').append(div);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o86upesc/2/).

Comment: Don't clone, use `.detach()`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon ooh, I'd forgotten about that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but the simplest/fastest version I could come up with is:

```
var form = $('td.ms-formbody');
form.html(form.children().detach());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/o86upesc/4/

This uses the version of `html()` that takes jQuery objects (instead of a string). It also does not care what the other children are, so is a bit more flexible to change.

Karl-André Gagnon's marked answer is still the best. I just wanted to see what shorter alternatives were available :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sputility = $(".sputility-readonly");
$(".ms-formbody").empty();
$(".ms-formbody").append(sputility);
```

Comment: You are missing "." in selectors :)

Comment: Ah, Yes! Corrected now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : clone the children of `td` and then put these children in html of main `td`

```
var children = $('td.ms-formbody').children().clone();
$('td.ms-formbody').html(children);
```